# mapping a map JPA, hibernate key

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa-2.0, hibernate-mapping

How can I map a map?

I have this:

```
private Map<Integer, Trip> trips = new HashMap<Integer, Trip>();
```

As mapkey I want the trip id..

The Trip entity is holding the reference to my entity. (the column is in another table).
The trip has a column to my reference id.

How can I do that?

Something like

```
@MapKeyTable(name="trips")
@MapKeyColumn(name="trip_id")
@OneToMany(joinTable......)
private Map<Integer, Trip> trips = new HashMap<Integer, Trip>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If trip id is a property of `Trip` (say `tripId`), then you need the following:

```
@MapKey(name = "tripId")
@OneToMany(...)
private Map<Integer, Trip> trips = new HashMap<Integer, Trip>();
```

Other annotations are for more complex cases.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinTable(name = "jointableName", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "this_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "trip_id"))
private Map<Integer, Trip> trips= new Hashtable<Integer, Trip>();
```